# How to retrieve object from xml

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to get the value of bank_name in php. Can't get it to display.

```
stdClass Object ( [account_id] => 43726384 [name] => Account Name [state] => action_required [description] => [owner_user_id] =>[type] => personal [create_time] => 1477684534 [disablement_time] => [country] => US [currencies] => Array ( [0] => USD ) [action_reasons] => Array ( [0] => kyc [1] => bank_account ) [disabled_reasons] => Array ( ) [image_uri] => [supported_card_types] => Array ( [0] => visa [1] => mastercard [2] => american_express [3] => discover [4] => jcb [5] => diners_club ) [gaq_domains] => Array ( [0] => ) [balances] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [balance] => 0 [currency] => USD [disputed_amount] => 0 [incoming_pending_amount] => 0 [outgoing_pending_amount] => 0 [reserved_amount] => 0 [bank_name] => Bank Of America [withdrawal_next_time] => [withdrawal_period] => [withdrawal_type] => ) ) [statuses] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [currency] => USD [incoming_payments_status] => ok [outgoing_payments_status] => paused [account_review_status] => not_requested ) ) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not very clear if you display data that way, but I think this would be the way to access to `bank_name`:

```
$bankName = $object->balances[0]->bank_name;
```

(If it doesn't work, please show the XML before parsing it to an object)

Comment: @denis Glad for it! Please don't forget to always validate the right answer.